# How to simulate data to run a random-intercept cross-lagged panel model?

Tags: simulation, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'd like to run a power calculation involving a random-intercept cross-lagged panel model. To do so, I need to simulate data with the relevant structure (e.g., between and within-person effects). Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new R package for that (`powRICLPM`, on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=powRICLPM) and [GitHub](https://jeroendmulder.github.io/powRICLPM/)), with an accompanying tutorial article:

https://doi.org/10.1080/10705511.2022.2122467

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but need to edit the model for mediation and moderation tests (not just run the basic RI-CLPM)  and the power calculator doesn’t do that. So I wanted to simulate the data myself in order to apply an altered RI-CLPM. The accompanying tutorial doesn’t give an overview on how the data simulation works, only how the function to calculate power works.

Comment: You can use the `simsem` package to run simulations for any SEM that lavaan or OpenMx can handle.  You can specify a `lavaan` syntax or `mxModel` object to analyze the data you will expect to have (the `sim(model=)` argument), and specify population parameters for the same model to use for data-generation (the `sim(generate=)` argument).  Find vignettes on simsem.org